# Cascading in JPA+ Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, cascade

Bellow are my entities:

```
public class EntityA {

   //...
   @OneToMany(mappedBy="entityA")
   private Set entitieBs;

}

public class EntityB {

   //...
   @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST)
   private EntityA entityA;

}

with accessors methods(getters and setters).
```

I intend that every time when I save a new **EntityB** object in the database (with an **EntityA** object set up as the "parent"), if I call **EntityA.getEntityBs()** on the parent of new **EntityB**, to have it added in the result *Set*. But if I do it as in my example it doesn't work.

Does anybody know where I am wrong?

Thanks!

---

Here is my java code how I persist the entity:

```
//...some code
EntityB eb = new EntityB();
eb.setEntityA(entityA);
entityManager.persist(entityB);
```

I want to make clear that I don't add **entityB** to **entityA**'s set of  entityBs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question is asked every two days.

JPA doesn't maintain the coherence of the object graph for you. It's **your** responsibility to maintain both sides of a bidirectional association. Everything will be as you expect if you commit the transaction, close the session, and reload the entities, because you have initialized the owning side of the association. But if you modify one side of the association in memory, JPA won't modify the other side for you.

Comment: A flush and a refresh of entityA should be enough to get the right values, if you don't want to commit yet.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I have a question. In the first approach I put the *entityManager* initialization in the servlet *init()* function. That leads me to inconsistency. Finally, as you have mentioned, I put the *entityMAnager* initialization in my business method (*doPost()*), without any *cascade* being specified, and it works very well. So, what's the use of *cascading*, if I need to recreate *EntityManager* after such an operation? I mean that with *cascade* or without it, the needed work will be the same. Note: I use Apache Tomcat 7 as server. It isn't a JavaEE AS.

Comment: cascade means thet an operation done on an entity is also done on the associated entity. For example, you persist A, and B is also persisted. You delete A, and B is also deleted. It has noting to do with the coherence of the object graph, and nothing todo with the way the em is created.